# C pointers : pointing to an array of fixed size

Tags: c, pointers, size

This question goes out to the C gurus out there:

In C, it is possible to declare a pointer as follows:

```
char (* p)[10];
```

.. which basically states that this pointer points to an array of 10 chars. The neat thing about declaring a pointer like this is that you will get a compile time error if you try to assign a pointer of an array of different size to p. It will also give you a compile time error if you try to assign the value of a simple char pointer to p. I tried this with gcc and it seems to work with ANSI, C89 and C99.

It looks to me like declaring a pointer like this would be very useful - particularly, when passing a pointer to a function. Usually, people would write the prototype of such a function like this:

```
void foo(char * p, int plen);
```

If you were expecting a buffer of an specific size, you would simply test the value of plen. However, you cannot be guaranteed that the person who passes p to you will really give you plen valid memory locations in that buffer. You have to trust that the person who called this function is doing the right thing. On the other hand:

```
void foo(char (*p)[10]);
```

..would force the caller to give you a buffer of the specified size.

This seems very useful but I have never seen a pointer declared like this in any code I have ever ran across.

My question is: Is there any reason why people do not declare pointers like this? Am I not seeing some obvious pitfall?

Comment: note: Since C99 the array does not have to be of fixed size as suggested by the title, `10` can be replaced by any variable in scope

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would like to add to AndreyT's answer (in case anyone stumbles upon this page looking for more info on this topic):

As I begin to play more with these declarations, I realize that there is major handicap associated with them in C (apparently not in C++). It is fairly common to have a situation where you would like to give a caller a const pointer to a buffer you have written into. Unfortunately, this is not possible when declaring a pointer like this in C. In other words, the C standard (6.7.3 - Paragraph 8) is at odds with something like this:

```
   int array[9];

   const int (* p2)[9] = &array;  /* Not legal unless array is const as well */
```

This constraint does not seem to be present in C++, making these type of declarations far more useful. But in the case of C, it is necessary to fall back to a regular pointer declaration whenever you want a const pointer to the fixed size buffer (unless the buffer itself was declared const to begin with). You can find more info in this mail thread: [link text](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-12/msg00026.html)

This is a severe constraint in my opinion and it could be one of the main reasons why people do not usually declare pointers like this in C. The other being the fact that most people do not even know that you can declare a pointer like this as AndreyT has pointed out.

Comment: That appears to be a compiler specific issue. I was able to duplicate using gcc 4.9.1, but clang 3.4.2 was able to go from a non-const to const version no problem. I did read the C11 spec (p 9 in my version... the part talking about two qualified types being compatible) and agree that it appears to say these conversions are illegal. However, we know in practice that you can always automatically convert from char* to char const* without warning. IMO, clang is more consistent in allowing this than gcc is, though I agree with you that the spec seems to prohibit any of these automatic conversions.

Comment: [GCC likes it.](https://godbolt.org/z/1hMq1Pvrq)

Comment: @Smiley1000: No, it doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/xsdhd97dh . This issue is planned to be resolved in C23. But currently it is still present in the language.

Answer (score 210):

What you are saying in your post is absolutely correct. I'd say that every C developer comes to exactly the same discovery and to exactly the same conclusion when (if) they reach certain level of proficiency with C language.

When the specifics of your application area call for an array of specific fixed size (array size is a compile-time constant), the only proper way to pass such an array to a function is by using a pointer-to-array parameter

```
void foo(char (*p)[10]);
```

(in C++ language this is also done with references

```
void foo(char (&p)[10]);
```

).

This will enable language-level type checking, which will make sure that the array of exactly correct size is supplied as an argument. In fact, in many cases people use this technique implicitly, without even realizing it, hiding the array type behind a typedef name

```
typedef int Vector3d[3];

void transform(Vector3d *vector);
/* equivalent to `void transform(int (*vector)[3])` */
...
Vector3d vec;
...
transform(&vec);
```

Note additionally that the above code is invariant with relation to `Vector3d` type being an array or a `struct`. You can switch the definition of `Vector3d` at any time from an array to a `struct` and back, and you won't have to change the function declaration. In either case the functions will receive an aggregate object "by reference" (there are exceptions to this, but within the context of this discussion this is true).

However, you won't see this method of array passing used explicitly too often, simply because too many people get confused by a rather convoluted syntax and are simply not comfortable enough with such features of C language to use them properly. For this reason, in average real life, passing an array as a pointer to its first element is a more popular approach. It just looks "simpler".

But in reality, using the pointer to the first element for array passing is a very niche technique, a trick, which serves a very specific purpose: its one and only purpose is to facilitate passing arrays of *different size* (i.e. run-time size). If you really need to be able to process arrays of run-time size, then the proper way to pass such an array is by a pointer to its first element with the concrete size supplied by an additional parameter

```
void foo(char p[], unsigned plen);
```

Actually, in many cases it is very useful to be able to process arrays of run-time size, which also contributes to the popularity of the method. Many C developers simply never encounter (or never recognize) the need to process a fixed-size array, thus remaining oblivious to the proper fixed-size technique.

Nevertheless, if the array size is fixed, passing it as a pointer to an element

```
void foo(char p[])
```

is a major technique-level error, which unfortunately is rather widespread these days. A pointer-to-array technique is a much better approach in such cases.

Another reason that might hinder the adoption of the fixed-size array passing technique is the dominance of naive approach to typing of dynamically allocated arrays. For example, if the program calls for fixed arrays of type `char[10]` (as in your example), an average developer will `malloc` such arrays as

```
char *p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p);
```

This array cannot be passed to a function declared as

```
void foo(char (*p)[10]);
```

which confuses the average developer and makes them abandon the fixed-size parameter declaration without giving it a further thought. In reality though, the root of the problem lies in the naive `malloc` approach. The `malloc` format shown above should be reserved for arrays of run-time size. If the array type has compile-time size, a better way to `malloc` it would look as follows

```
char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

This, of course, can be easily passed to the above declared `foo`

```
foo(p);
```

and the compiler will perform the proper type checking. But again, this is overly confusing to an unprepared C developer, which is why you won't see it in too often in the "typical" average everyday code.

Comment: The answer delivers a very concise and informative description of how sizeof() succeeds, how it often fails, and ways it always fails. your observations of most C/C++ engineers not understanding, and therefore doing something they think they do understand instead is one of the more prophetic things I've seen in awhile, and the veil is nothing compared to the accuracy it describes. seriously, sir. great answer.

Comment: I just refactored some code based on this answer, bravo and thanks for both the Q and the A.

Comment: @AndreyT: +1 Your answer got me thinking if in C++ will this `char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p);` be possible using the `new` expression? I asked a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19467909/183120).

Comment: I'm curious to know how you handle `const` property with this technique.
A `const char (*p)[N]` argument does not seem compatible with a pointer to `char table[N];`
By contrast, a simple `char*` ptr remain compatible with a `const char*` argument.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that to access an element of your array, you need to do `(*p)[i]` and not `*p[i]`. The latter will jump by the size of the array, which is almost certainly not what you want. At least for me, learning this syntax caused, rather than prevented, a mistake; I would have gotten correct code faster just passing a float*.

Comment: @Cyan wouldn't a const pointer to the char array be declared `char (* const p)[N]`? I'm asking, not saying, I'm not yet that proficient in C intricacies...

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't prevent the function from changing the things p points to...

Comment: Yes @mickey, what you have suggested is a `const` pointer to an array of mutable elements.
And yes, this is completely different from a pointer to an array of immutable elements.

Comment: @Smiley1000: Huh? You are calling `g` from `g`. You haven't tested anything. Here's a real version of your test: https://godbolt.org/z/doYhGnsxq

Answer (score 3):

The obvious reason is that this code doesn't compile:

```
extern void foo(char (*p)[10]);
void bar() {
  char p[10];
  foo(p);
}
```

The default promotion of an array is to an unqualified pointer.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array), using `foo(&p)` should work.

Comment: Of course foo(p) will not work, foo is asking for a pointer to an array of 10 elements so you need to pass the address of your array...

Comment: How is that the "obvious reason"? It is, obviously, understood that the proper way to call the function is `foo(&p)`.

Comment: I guess "obvious" is the wrong word.  I meant "most straightforward".  The distinction between p and &p in this case is quite obscure to the average C programmer.  Someone trying to do what the poster suggested will write what I wrote, get a compile-time error, and give up.

Answer (score 3):

I also want to use this syntax to enable more type checking.

But I also agree that the syntax and mental model of using pointers is simpler, and easier to remember.

Here are some more obstacles I have come across.

- Accessing the array requires using `(*p)[]`:

  ```
  void foo(char (*p)[10])
  {
      char c = (*p)[3];
      (*p)[0] = 1;
  }
  ```

  It is tempting to use a local pointer-to-char instead:

  ```
  void foo(char (*p)[10])
  {
      char *cp = (char *)p;
      char c = cp[3];
      cp[0] = 1;
  }
  ```

  But this would partially defeat the purpose of using the correct type.
- One has to remember to use the address-of operator when assigning an array's address to a pointer-to-array:

  ```
  char a[10];
  char (*p)[10] = &a;
  ```

  The address-of operator gets the address of the whole array in `&a`, with the correct type to assign it to `p`.  Without the operator, `a` is automatically converted to the address of the first element of the array, same as in `&a[0]`, which has a different type.

  Since this automatic conversion is already taking place, I am always puzzled that the `&` is necessary. It is consistent with the use of `&` on variables of other types, but I have to remember that an array is special and that I need the `&` to get the correct type of address, even though the address value is the same.

  One reason for my problem may be that I learned K&R C back in the 80s, which did not allow using the `&` operator on whole arrays yet (although some compilers ignored that or tolerated the syntax). Which, by the way, may be another reason why pointers-to-arrays have a hard time to get adopted: they only work properly since ANSI C, and the `&` operator limitation may have been another reason to deem them too awkward.
- When `typedef` is *not* used to create a type for the pointer-to-array (in a common header file), then a global pointer-to-array needs a more complicated `extern` declaration to share it across files:

  ```
  fileA:
  char (*p)[10];

  fileB:
  extern char (*p)[10];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply put, C doesn't do things that way. An array of type `T` is passed around as a pointer to the first `T` in the array, and that's all you get.

This allows for some cool and elegant algorithms, such as looping through the array with expressions like

```
*dst++ = *src++
```

The downside is that management of the size is up to you. Unfortunately, failure to do this conscientiously has also led to millions of bugs in C coding, and/or opportunities for malevolent exploitation.

What comes close to what you ask in C is to pass around a `struct` (by value) or a pointer to one (by reference). As long as the same struct type is used on both sides of this operation, both the code that hand out the reference and the code that uses it are in agreement about the size of the data being handled.

Your struct can contain whatever data you want; it could contain your array of a well-defined size.

Still, nothing prevents you or an incompetent or malevolent coder from using casts to fool the compiler into treating your struct as one of a different size. The almost unshackled ability to do this kind of thing is a part of C's design.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array of characters a number of ways:

```
char p[10];
char* p = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

The prototype to a function that takes an array by value is:

```
void foo(char* p); //cannot modify p
```

or by reference:

```
void foo(char** p); //can modify p, derefernce by *p[0] = 'f';
```

or by array syntax:

```
void foo(char p[]); //same as char*
```

Comment: Don't forget that a fixed-size array can also be dynamically allocated as `char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p)`.

Comment: See here for a more detailed discussion between the differences of char array[] and char *ptr here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807530/difference-between-using-character-pointers-and-character-arrays/1807766#1807766

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this solution

```
typedef int Vector3d[3];
```

since it obscures the fact that Vector3D has a type that you
must know about. Programmers usually dont expect variables of the
same type to have different sizes. Consider :

```
void foo(Vector3d a) {
   Vector3d b;
}
```

where sizeof a != sizeof b

Comment: He was not suggesting this as a solution. He was simply using this as an example.

Comment: Hm. Why is `sizeof(a)` not the same as `sizeof(b)`?

Comment: @sherrellbc because arrays as function arguments implicitly decay to pointers to them, so this is basically equivalent to `void foo(Vector3d *a)`.

Comment: You have a typo in the declaration (it should be lower case 3d).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but... since arrays are constant pointers, basically that means that there's no point in passing around pointers to them.

Couldn't you just use `void foo(char p[10], int plen);` ?

Comment: For what matters here (unidimensional arrays as parameters), the fact is that they decay to constant pointers. Read a FAQ on how to be less pedantic, please.

Answer (score 0):

```c
 type (*)[]; 
// points to an array e.g
int (*ptr)[5];
// points to an 5 integer array
// gets the address of the array

type *[];
// points to an array of pointers e.g
int* ptr[5]
// point to an array of five integer pointers
// point to 5 adresses.
```

Answer (score -3):

On my compiler (vs2008) it treats `char (*p)[10]` as an array of character pointers, as if there was no parentheses, even if I compile as a C file. Is compiler support for this "variable"? If so that is a major reason not to use it.

Comment: -1 Wrong. It works fine on vs2008, vs2010, gcc. In particular this example works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19208364/2333290