# C argument definition problem

Tags: c

When I want to pass a "`char (*c)[10];`" as a parameter,
what argument should I define in my function definition?

I mean, if I have a function:

```
void foo(*****) { ... }
```

I want to pass `char (*c)[10];` to it, so what do I write in place of `*****`?

Comment: Any reason `void foo(char (*c)[10]);` is undoable passed as `foo(c)`?

Comment: Typedefs usually make function pointers much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
void foo(char (*c)[10]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass it simply as you're declaring it:

```
void foo(char (*c)[10]);
```

And call it as:

```
foo(c);
```

This is the best post on this subject: [C pointers : pointing to an array of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size)

Answer (score 1):

Define the function as:

```
void foo(char (*c)[10])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*c); i++)
        printf("%d: %c\n", i, (*c)[i]);
}
```

Use the function as:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[10] = "abcdefghi";
    char (*c)[10] = &a;
    foo(c);
    return(0);
}
```