# What is the difference between these two C declarations?

Tags: c

I was at an interview today, and was asked the difference between the following two declarations:

```
int *A[10];
```

and

```
int (*A)[10];
```

which I did not know. If you think I am missing some important pointer 'pointer', please let me know that too. Thanks.

Comment: When in doubt [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations

Comment: You may also find this old thread useful: [C pointers: pointing to an array of fixed size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first declares an array of ten pointers to `int`, the second a pointer to an array of ten `int`s.

The `[]` binds tighter than the `*`, so the first could equivalently be written

```
int *(A[10]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
int *A[10];  // an array of 10 int pointers
```

the relative precedences of the unary `*`  and `[]`makes this equivalent to

```
int *(A[10]);  // same
```

The second declaration changes that implicit ordering to

```
int (*A)[10]; // a pointer to an array of ten ints
```

[C and C++ Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs240/misc/operators.html)

Comment: This is about precedence, not associativity, no?