# Trying to write a function that takes an array of specific length, getting weird inconsistant results with no errors

Tags: c, linux

I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float mat4f[16];

void logMat(mat4f in) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        //in[i] = i; //uncomment this line and it works as expected
        printf("%2d: %f\n", i, in[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    mat4f a;
    logMat(a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the elements at index 4 and 12 often appear corrupted. 
Some examples:

```
 0: 0.000000
 1: 0.000000
 2: 0.000000
 3: 0.000000
 4: -0.019316
 5: 0.000000
 6: 0.000000
 7: 0.000000
 8: 0.000000
 9: 0.000000
10: 0.000000
11: 0.000000
12: -0.000000
13: 0.000000
14: 0.000000
15: 0.000000
```

or

```
 0: 0.000000
 1: 0.000000
 2: 0.000000
 3: 0.000000
 4: 894113943650304.000000
 5: 0.000000
 6: 0.000000
 7: 0.000000
 8: 0.000000
 9: 0.000000
10: 0.000000
11: 0.000000
12: 0.002546
13: 0.000000
14: 0.000000
15: 0.000000
```

And I get different results just from running it multiple times.
However, if I uncomment that one line that you'll see in the source, it works as expected every time.

Can anyone spot my mistake? Why index 4 and 12?

I'm kinda trying to do what was suggested here: [stackoverflow.com/a/1810295/1472246](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810295/1472246)

Comment: You mistake is removing that line.

Comment: You dont initialize your array

Comment: `a` is uninitialized. and sdtio.h -> stdio.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a feature of C. It is often a source of tricky bugs though.

The problem is the line:

```
mat4f a;
```

It only reserves space for the variable `a`. It does not actually set it to any value. So `a` will have the value of the data that was there previously. It is often zero, but from time to time it is something else.

One way to also set `a` to zero is to declare it with an initializer:

```
mat4f a = {0};
```

Comment: Empty initializer list is forbidden by C99. Should be `mat4f a = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

Variables in C which are not either global or static are not guaranteed to be initialised to any particular value.

So after the line

```
mat4f a;
```

the values of the elements of a can be anything.  In terms of the C language standard reading those uninitialised values invokes undefined behaviour - anything can happen.

Your commented out line explicitly sets the element values so it works as expected.