# How do I pass a member of a union by reference

Tags: c, pointers, structure, unions

I have a union declared like:

```
typedef union {
    mpls_vpls_t Vpls_dat; //typedef struct
    mpls_vpws_t Vpws_dat; //typedef struct
}ser_cache_t;
```

and I allocate memory for it:

```
ser_dat_ch = calloc(LABEL_T_CNT,sizeof(ser_cache_t));
if (ser_dat_ch == NULL)
    return ERROR;
```

while `static ser_cache_t *ser_dat_ch = NULL;` is global.

Now I want to populate my union with data and hence I wantto pass a pointer to it to a function like:
`rv = switch_mpls_vpws_data_get(lab, &ser_dat_ch->Vpws_dat[lab]);`
But here the compiler screams: **expression must have pointer-to-object type**
why so, won't `&ser_dat_ch->Vpws_dat[lab]` resolve to the address I'm looking for?

Comment: what is `mpls_vpws_t`? If that's not an array typedef, you obviously can't use `Vpws_dat[lab]`. Maybe you meant `&ser_dat_ch[lab].Vpws_dat`

Comment: @M.M Both structures are `typedef struct`

Comment: You can't. C does not support pass by reference. But you can pass a pointer to the union (aka its address). See [ask], provide a [mcve]. You also want to read about operator preceedence.

Comment: saying "C does not support pass by reference" is like saying "C does not support linked lists"

Comment: @M.M Olaf is actually right - You may say, C *simulates* PBR by passing around pointers. Effectively, it's the same thing, except when it isn't (you can't pass an **array** by reference, because it loses its array traits)

Comment: @tofro You can pass a pointer to an array, just the same as a pointer to any other type.  The array doesn't lose its array traits. You don't see it very often because passing a pointer to the array's first element suffices for most purposes and has simpler syntax

Comment: @M.M If it were a *true reference*, you could treat it with `sizeof` and you'd get the size of the array. But you cannot. And exactly that array trait is lost. I hope you don't mix up C and C++ here. We're talking C

Comment: @tofro yes, you can use `sizeof` and get the size of the array. Yes this is a C question.

Comment: @M.M Now you've made me interested. Can you give an example? My compilers can't do that.

Comment: @tofro [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/). I suspect you are mixing up "pointer to array" with "pointer to first element of array". The latter loses type information (i.e. length) about the array but the former doesn't

Comment: Nice, thanks. I even used to know that long ago but apparently decided to forget because you don't use it much, normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have an array of such unions and one pointer to the start of that memory. Then, accessing one of the ith element's structure member would look like

```
ser_dat_ch[i].Vpws_dat
```

and a pointer to that union is

```
&(ser_dat_ch[i])
```

and a pointer to one of the structs in the union (that is apparently what you're looking for) is

```
&(ser_dat_ch[i].Vpws_dat)
```

Comment: Thanks for the eye opener!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to your post (not enough reputation).  The error you're getting usually hints that the function parameter is not the correct type for the pointer.  I.e. passing a single dimension pointer to a multi dimension pointer.

Additionally, your syntax is problematic:

```
rv = switch_mpls_vpws_data_get(lab, &ser_dat_ch->Vpws_dat[lab]);
```

`&set_dat_ch->Vpws_dat[lab]` is messy syntax.  To be honest, I'm not even sure what would evaluate first `Vpws_dat[lab]` then `ser_dat_ch->` then finally `&`.  You should just simplify this (although through parenthesis you could get the desired effect).  Either pass the internal struct `ser_dat_ch->Vpws_dat` and retrieve the variable inside the function, or prior to the function do something like:

```
int *var = ser_dat_ch->Vpws_dat
```

And then just pass var to the function.  Note: I just used an `int*` because I'm unsure what the internal implementation is.