# sizeof array without explicit length

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Can `sizeof` safely be used on an array that has been declared without an explicit size specified inside the square brackets, but which gets initialised in the declaration?

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
size_t bytes = sizeof arr;
```

If compiled on macOS with clang-800.0.42.1 without any special compiler flags, this yields the expected result of `12`.
But does the C standard (or *any* C standard, if they differ on this) guarantee this to be the case? Or do I have to declare it like `unsigned int arr[3]` in order for it to be "sane"?

Comment: Yes. The compiler knows the size.

Comment: I would also like to know if `sizeof( arr )` would work when it would be inside a function where the function header is  something like `void somefunction ( int arr[], int n );`  because from a calling routine you could pass any pointer of type `*int` in to `somefunction`.

Comment: @ron - no, it would not, because what `somefunction` receives is a pointer, not an array.  Within the function, `sizeof arr` would give you the same result as `sizeof (int *)`.

Comment: No, When passed to a function, the size is only the size of a pointer. Not the size of the array

Comment: @ron I don't think so, I believe `int arr[]` is just a nicer way of writing `int *arr` so you'll get the size of the pointer

Comment: @User9182736455 You are very wrong. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @ron no, it does not work on an array which is a function argument, it gives the size of the pointer to which the array passed decays.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know but when passing an array to a function you instead pass the address of the first element; thus it contains no information about the length. You probably missed that I was talking about **passing arrays to functions**

Comment: @User9182736455 That's correct. But you still can't use `arr[]` an lvalue, for example.

Comment: BTW, [an interesting and a non-obvious related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think @User9182736455 was trying to say `int arr[]` and `int *arr` are the same in **function signature declaration** only

Comment: @ysap Would you mind justifying the edit you made?

Comment: Mmm... C notation? If this was intentional (sorry, I miss how), then I can revert the change.

Comment: @ysap Well, I just like to not write parentheses unless they're required. In this case, they're not.

Comment: In case you care - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initialize

Comment: @ysap https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252504

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the standard guarantees that the array element count will be equal to the number of elements in the array initializer in case no size is specified. See
[C11 standard draft 6.7.9p22](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p22) and [6.7.9p25](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p25):

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by
>   the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. The array
>   type is completed at the end of its initializer list.
>
> EXAMPLE 2 The declaration
>
> ```
> int x[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
> ```
>
> defines and initializes `x` as a one-dimensional array object that has three elements, as no size was specified and there are three initializers.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` actually *defines* a complete array. The size of the array is known in this compilation unit and is n*sizeof(type) where n is the number of elements in the initialization list (here 3) and type is the underlying object type (here `unsigned int`).

That means that `sizeof(arr)` is defined in same scope as `arr` and has the expected value.

---

What would be completely different would be `extern int arr[];`. That would be a simple *declaration* that an array of that name will be provided in another compilation unit, but the compiler has no way to know its size. In that case using `sizeof(arr)` will be an error.

Another example of mere declaration is

```
void func(int arr[]) {
    ...
}
```

Here again the compiler only knows that the function will receive an int array, but again cannot know its size. But here the compiler generates a pointer that will receive the address of the array and `sizeof(arr)` is defined but is the size of that pointer and **not** the size of the original array.

Comment: No, in your third example the compiler *doesn't* know that the function will receive an array. `void func(int arr[])` is exactly equivalent to `void func(int *arr)`; the declaration is "adjusted" at compile time. It's perfectly legal, for example, to call `func(NULL)`, or `func(&n)` where `n` is an `int` object that's not an array element.