# Incompatible C Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *p; 
    char str[100];
    p = &str;

    return 0;
}
```

What is this incompatible pointer type thing? I'm searching for an hour but couldn't find anything that cover the conceptual part of it.
And what am I doing wrong here, that causes this warning?

Comment: Change `p = &str;` to either `p = str;` or `p = &str[0];`.

Comment: you must assign p with first address of str. First address of str is &str[0] or str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler expects a pointer to `char` but tried to assign pointer to `char[100]`. That's not the same :)

See these for more detailed discussion:

[C pointers : pointing to an array of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size)

[C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

`&str` of type `char (*)[100]` which is incompatible with the type `char *`. What you need is just assign `str` to `p` as array decay to pointer to it's first element when used in an expression except when an operand of  `sizeof` and unary `&` operator.

Comment: I'm quite confused of `char (*)[100] vs char *` Can you suggest me a resource so I can learn about this subject matter.

Comment: @LeftOver what is confusing exactly? `char` is not the same as `char[100]`, so pointers to those are not the same either.

Comment: @LeftOver Reading non-trivial C type specifiers can be confusing for the beginner, especially because they contain no identifier for a variable (or parameter or whatever). Here are some type specifiers and matching variable declarations: `char`: `char x;` (single `char`); `char[100]`: `char x[100];` (array of 100 `char`); `char *`: `char *x;` (pointer to `char`); `char *[100]`: `char *x[100];` (array of 100 pointers to `char`); `char (*)[100]`: `char (*x)[100];` (pointer to array of 100 `char`).

Answer (score 2):

`str` is typed `char[100]`.

So taking it's address using the `&`-operator, gives you an address of a `char[100]`, not the address of a `char`.

The relevance of the difference becomes obvious if you think on how pointer arithmetic works:

Incrementing a pointer by 1 moves its value as many bytes as the type uses the pointer points to. Which is 100 for a pointer to `char[100]` and just 1 for a pointer to `char`.

---

To define a pointer to an array the somewhat unintuitive notation

```
T (*<name>)[<dimension>]
```

is used.

So a pointer to `char[100]` would be

```
char (*ps)[100];
```

So one can write:

```
char str[100];
char (*ps)[100] = &str; // make ps point to str
```

to have `ps` point to the *array* `str`.

Doing

```
char * p = str;
```

makes `p` point to the 1st element of `str`, which is a `char`.

The interesting thing is that `p` and `ps` point to the same address. :-)

But if you'd do

```
ps = ps + 1;
```

`ps` got incremented *100* bytes, whereas when doing

```
p = p + 1;
```

`p` got incremented just *one* byte.