# Difference in methods to pass array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

Is there a difference between defining:

```
void example(int usuario[]);
```

or

```
void example(int usuario[SIZE]);
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `c`, the array name when passed decays to a pointer. Using a `sizeof` in both your examples on  `usario` will return the size of an int pointer, regardless of `SIZE`. So both examples are identical, and are the same as

```
void example (int *usario)
```

The `[]` syntax in this context is purely syntactic sugar. Functionally, a pointer will be what you are actually working with - the `[]` or `[SIZE]` are only useful for a future programmer to see you **expect** an array with length `SIZE`. This will not be enforced by the compiler at all.

On a modern compiler, you will get a warning if you do `sizeof(usario)` in the function - you can try it with both your examples.