# const char myVar* vs. const char myVar[]

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using character pointers and character arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807530/difference-between-using-character-pointers-and-character-arrays)

What's the difference between:

```
const char* myVar = "Hello World!";
const char  myVar[] = "Hello World!";
```

If there is one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pointer can be reassigned, the array cannot.

```
const char* ptr = "Hello World!";
const char  arr[] = "Hello World!";

ptr = "Goodbye"; // okay
arr = "Goodbye"; // illegal
```

Also, as others have said:

```
sizeof(ptr) == size of a pointer, usually 4 or 8
sizeof(arr) == number of characters + 1 for null terminator
```

Comment: +1 I think this is a more appropriate answer to the question given

Answer (score 5):

First is a pointer.
Second is an array.

Size of all pointers in an system will be the same.
Size of the array in second declaration is same as the size of the string literal plus the `\0`.

You can point the first pointer to any other variable of the same type.
You cannot reassign the array.

Answer (score 2):

The first is a pointer: `sizeof(myVar) == sizeof(void*)`. It is non-constant, so you can modify it: `myVar++`.

The second is an array: `sizeof(myVar) == 13`.