# Weird char array behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm thrilled. Why does this works fine:

```
char ptr[] = "hello world!";
ptr[0] = 'H';
printf("%s\n", ptr); // prints "Hello world!"
```

and this:

```
char * ptr = "hello world!";
ptr[0] = 'H';
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

raises a `Segmentation Fault`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use const char * and when to use const char \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903551/when-to-use-const-char-and-when-to-use-const-char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the ptr[] is modifiable by the standard but the char * is not. The char * uses a const string which can be used many times over in the program the array actually creates a new array and copies your string to it.

By the way this should give a compile error - you must use

```
const char *ptr="Hello";
```

Adding some more - basically the compiler is allowed to look for every string in quotes and place it in a read only string table. Because a 1000 place in your program could use and define the string "this". The compiler can get smart and convert those 1000 "this" to just 1 because they are all the same - because of this it becomes read only - So now one location cannot modify the fixed string after compile time - because it will break you expected output from your program.

Comment: if I comment the line `ptr[0]  = 'H';` it works fine, no compile error

Comment: If you are using a real c++ compiler you wil get this. [adrian@iceweasel ~]$ g++ a.cc
a.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
a.cc:3:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ cat a.cc
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *ptr="Hello";
   return 0;
}

Comment: ah ok! I'm getting that too, but that's a warning, not an error.

Comment: :-) if its a warning - its an error. Compilers dont complain about correct code. The reason its just a warning is for compatibility with old code. My personal opinion is to compile with every warning on - then each can be checked.

Answer (score 3):

In case 1, `ptr` is a character array whose contents can be changed

In case 2, `ptr` is a pointer to a *string literal* which is usually stored in read-only section. Changing it leads to undefined behaviour. Segfault is one manifestation of that.