# googletest doc C string and string

Tags: c++, c, string, googletest

I am reading [Googletest doc](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Assertions), and I am learning that there is one syntax for comparing string, and another for comparing C string. I dont see what is referred to as C string and as string. How are these different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` is often called `C++ string`. Using strings like

```
 const char *text = "text";
```

is called CStrings.

much more information can be found here:

[What is the difference between char * const and const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

[When to use const char * and when to use const char []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903551/when-to-use-const-char-and-when-to-use-const-char)

Answer (score 12):

If you try to use `ASSERT_EQ` to C-Strings, you only compare two pointers, but not really null-terminated C-Strings. For that exists `ASSERT_STREQ` syntax.