# Array initialization: memory usage

Tags: c, arrays, memory

#### CONTEXT

I am studying the array definitions. My question sticks with char array for simplicity.
Debian 64bit.

#### PROBLEM

When I declare those arrays, here is my understanding :

```
char d[10];
```

=> I get 10 * 1 byte memory usage.

```
char d[] = "hellofooo";
```

=> 9 bytes + '\0' => 10 * 1 byte memory usage

```
char * d = "hellofooo";
```

=> 9 bytes + '\0' somewhere in the memory + 8 bytes for the pointer (64 bits)

So, if my understanding is good, we should always prefer the second solution [] to minimise the memory consumption when we do not know upfront the size of the char?

There is no need for pointers in my code. Just trying to find the most ram efficient solution.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are completely different semantically. And 2 you get potentially the string literal somewhere in non-modifiable memory + a copy of that stored in `d`.

Comment: So 2 and 3 have the same effect in ram usage ? considering i don't need pointers;

Comment: No, 2) is potentially more costly (10+10), but that's absolutely not a reason to choose one over the other - they don't do the same thing at all.

Comment: All other things equal, I use `char const d[] = "hellofooo";`. You should find that the compiler just makes `d` designate the string directly in the string table.

Comment: And for completeness: The 3rd case does **not** define an array but a pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903551/when-to-use-const-char-and-when-to-use-const-char

Comment: @MattMcNabb : Mat said that there is a copy in d anyway, which would tend to a higher memory usage in final. So ? What should I do ? to fulfill my goal ?

Comment: @alk : exact. I took a shortcut there.

Comment: @Larry Conceptually `d` is separate to the string literal, but in practice this gets optimized so that `d` designates the string literal.

Comment: Of course the same thing could happen if you went `char const *const d = "hellofooo";` , this is really an aesthetics issue

Comment: Thanks you all. In case I don't need pointers, I will use 2 and 3 in other cases.

Comment: @MattMcNabb isn't that `const char *const d = "hellofooo";`?

Comment: @PeterVaro those have the same meaning but I think `char const` is better style . it's consistent with how `const` applies in more complicated declarations. Left-most `const` is a special case.

Comment: well, this is probably the question of personal preferences, but for me saying `const char` and then `*const d` is more powerful, as it is: *"declare d as const pointer to pointer to const char"*

Comment: that isn't what it means.. there's only one level of pointing.

Comment: oh ofc, you are right.. it is *declare d as const pointer to const char* -- silly me, sorry..