# Compilation error appears because of missing const?

Tags: c++, constants, strcpy

I am trying to run a code that defines objects that are a collection of English letters.
    I dont know why it does not compile.

```
I have tried to change from int to const int but it is not the case,
```

and also added the disable 4996 message but it didnt help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class CharSet
{
    int size;
    char* pSet;
public:
    // -----------------------------------
    CharSet(int const size, char* set)
    {
        this->size = size;
        pSet = new char[strlen(set) + 1];
        strcpy(pSet, set);
    }
    // -----------------------------------

    ~CharSet()
    {
        delete[] pSet;
    }
    // -----------------------------------

    CharSet operator*(const CharSet & other)
    {
        int maxSize = 0;
        if (this->size >= other.size)
            maxSize = this->size;
        else
            maxSize = other.size;

        char * ret = new char[maxSize + 1];
        char temp;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        {
            temp = this->pSet[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < other.size; j++)
            {
                if (other.pSet[j] == temp)
                {
                    ret[index] = temp;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        ret[index] = '\0';

        return CharSet(maxSize, ret);
    }

    // -----------------------------------

    bool operator()(char check)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        {
            if (pSet[i] == check)
                flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    // -----------------------------------

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CharSet& s)
    {
        os << s.pSet;
        return os;
    }

    // -----------------------------------
};

int main()
{
    CharSet s1(4, "DAQP"), s2(3, "AXZ");
    cout << s1 * s2 << endl;
    if (s1('Q') == true)
        cout << "The element is member of the set" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The element is not member of the set" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

errors:

1. E0289    no instance of constructor "CharSet::CharSet" matches the argument
2. E0289    no instance of constructor "CharSet::CharSet" matches the argument list
3. C4996    'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
4. C2664    'CharSet::CharSet(const CharSet &)': cannot convert argument 2 from
5. C2664    'CharSet::CharSet(const CharSet &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [4]' to 'char *'

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that calculation of `maxSize` would be much simpler as `int maxSize = std::max(size, other.size);`.

Comment: String literal `"DAQP"` is of type `const char[5]`, which binds to `const char*`. But your constructor accepts `char*`, which string literals can't bind to.

Comment: why don't you use string?

Comment: Why patronize? There is a way to explain things. Thanks. @WhozCraig

Comment: Compiler errors sure have come a long way since "Syntax error on line 1062." Most of the time you couldn't even trust the line number.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Why answer in the comments section?

Answer (score 2):

you need a `const char*` in your constructor:

```
CharSet(int const size, const char* set)
```

Thanks to 
[@holy black cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat)
 `"DAQP"` is a `const char[]` which you didn't provide a constructor for that(the array will implicitly convert to pointer).

---

A better way is using `std::string`:

```
class CharSet
{
 std::string pSet;
public:
// -----------------------------------
CharSet(std::string set) : pSet(set)
{
}
// -----------------------------------

~CharSet()
{
}
// -----------------------------------

CharSet operator*(const CharSet & other)
{
    int maxSize = 0;

    std::string ret;
    char temp;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pSet.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = pSet[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < other.pSet.size(); j++)
        {
            if (other.pSet[j] == temp)
            {
                ret += temp;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    return CharSet(ret);
}
// the rest of members ...
//
};
```

full code at [godblot](https://godbolt.org/z/KfwJBA)

Comment: thank you!! the other error is with the strcpy. the visual studio tell me to use srtcpy_s, but it is still not work.

Comment: @LORINECHERRY the remaining error is Visiual Studio  warning you that `strcpy` has a number of fabulously deadly and often utterly silent failure cases. `srtcpy_s`  does nothing to fix these failure cases, but makes the failures extremely loud (default behaviour is to crash the program). It also has a different set of arguments, [so look it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=vs-2019) and make sure it is the right solution for you.

Comment: Also strongly consider using `std::string` in place of character arrays as they make most of the string manipulation problems starting programmers have next to impossible.

Comment: Ive got little bit confusing.. can you show me exmaple please? i am new to c++

Comment: @LORINECHERRY I'll add a string example

Comment: @LORINECHERRY I adapted your class to use string

Comment: Pardon my nitpicking, but `"DAQP"` is `const char [5]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you please elaborate. I always thought it is a const char*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903551/when-to-use-const-char-and-when-to-use-const-char

Comment: @Oblivion i am trying to compile your code at VS and it not compiling :(

Comment: @LORINECHERRY did you take it from godbolt?

Comment: yes yes yes yes (sorry the character couting thing i didnt had nothing else to say hehe)

Comment: @Oblivion Since arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers, the difference is subtle. It presents itself only in a few cases. E.g. `const char (&ref)[5] = "DAQP";` wouldn't compile if it was a pointer. Also `sizeof("DAQP")` is `5`, but for a pointer it would be equal to `sizeof(const char *)`.

Comment: yes its working thank you a lot!! there is a way here to talk in private if i have more questions? and it you want to answer of course.

Comment: @Oblivion I forgot that the function and the c'tor needs to apply the thing that each letter can only appear once. so string like 'Hello' cant be accept