# When should we use a char pointer ( char *) over a char array (char [] )?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Is there any situations where one type is preferred over the other?

The only thing I can think of is...

a pointer uses 4 bytes, and a char array's size depends on the length of the string, so if you have a really big string,it's beneficial to use a char pointer instead in order save memory example: if your passing strings around through arguments.

but in terms of string manipulation, which is preferred?

example:

```
char *hello_pointer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
char hello_array[20];

strcat(hello_pointer, "hello pointer");
strcat(hello_array, "hello array");
```

is there a preference for one over the other in this case?

Comment: Prefer using a `std::string`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between using character pointers and character arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807530/difference-between-using-character-pointers-and-character-arrays)

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're doing. Here you're missing something either way because you're concatenating with uninitialized strings.

Comment: On any computer made since 2012 a pointer will be 8 bytes, but that doesn't matter since that same computer surely has several gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Please pick either C or C++. They are different languages and the best answer may depend on which language you are actually using.

Comment: @Jules "so if you have a really big string,it's beneficial to use a char pointer instead in order save memory" A question arises where will the big string stored?:)

Comment: _so if you have a really big string,it's beneficial to use a char pointer instead in order save memory_: IMO yes, it seems a good idea: not to waste the stack especially in programs that make intensive use of recursion, e.g.: an interpreter.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `sizeof char` is always 1 by definition (the sizes are in units of 1 `char`), so multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary. If you wish to have the multiplication there for consistency or whatever, rather use the pattern `p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * count)` so that you don't repeat the type.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't about "saving memory", this is about dynamic allocation versus a fixed-length buffer.

In your example you're *assuming* that your data will be no more than 19 characters. This could be a huge mistake. The difference between `char* x` and `char x[20]` is not really relevant until you want to use that data outside the scope it was declared in.

A `char* x` allocated using `malloc` will persist outside the function's scope. A `char[20]` will not, you need to copy it before it gets recycled.

So in comparison, a buffer like `char x[20]`:

- effectively zero cost to create
- must be conservatively sized to avoid consuming too much stack space
- will need to be NUL terminated when declared, like `char x[20] = { 0 }`
- **cannot** be used once they fall out of function scope

Whereas `char* x`:

- has a small initialization cost
- must be released with `free` when no longer used or program will leak memory
- can be used outside of function scope
- must be initialized before use, may contain junk data

You're *100% responsible* for:

- properly initializing your character buffers
- ensuring that the buffers are the correct size for the data you intend to store in them
- informing any functions manipulating this buffer what the buffer's size is, or in some cases, what the *remaining* size is
- NUL terminating any buffers you manipulate where you may overwrite the terminator
- releasing any memory allocated dynamically

Typically you'll see fixed-length buffers used for things like reading in and parsing a file where you do so carefully and with awareness of your buffer's size limits. Reading functions that take a length argument are the ones you want to use even though there are some like `gets()` which are commonly shown. Those can and will create huge buffer-overflow bugs.

In C++ it's easy to avoid this mess and just use `std::string` which deals with all of this for you automatically.

Comment: I see. so its usage really depends on the kind of scope you need?

Comment: Exactly. If you want it temporarily, use an array, as these are basically zero cost. If you want it for longer, dynamically. Exception: If you need a buffer of non-trivial size (e.g. over 1024 bytes) use dynamic allocation as stack space is limited.

Comment: got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Difference is that with `malloc()` or `new` you will get memory allocated on the heap and this is slower and will not get destroyed with the end of the scope.
`char hello_array[20]` will be allocated on the stack and will be removed with the stack frame.

Also, with `malloc(sizeof(char) * 20)` you don't just allocate one pointer but memory block to handle 20 chars. Size will be the same.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks :)